# I have met this "Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'"

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

As I mentioned in the title, I have met this error "Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'", and I have already upgraded numpy to the latest version, so how could I solve this?